# mat-paginator change the placing of mat-paginator-range-label

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a simple `mat-table` with `mat-paginator`.

By default design it looks like this:
[image]

I would like to change the placing of the range label and put it between the navigation buttons, like this:

[image]

Basically, I need to move the `div.mat-paginator-range-label` an element from the top of this container between `button.mat-paginator-navigation-previous` and `button.mat-paginator-navigation-next`.

[image]

Any idea of how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually because the "mat-paginator-container" uses flexbox you can easily modify the default placing of all the components just with a custom CSS code. For instance for me:

```
// override material paginator
::ng-deep .mat-paginator {
    .mat-paginator-container {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    // override material paginator page switch
    .mat-paginator-range-label {
        order: 2;
    }

    .mat-paginator-navigation-previous {
        order: 1;
    }
    .mat-paginator-navigation-next {
        order: 3;
    }
}
```

If you are using the MDC-based Components then you need to add `mdc` to the class as bellow.

```
  // override material paginator
  .mat-mdc-paginator-outer-container {
    .mat-mdc-paginator-container {
      justify-content: center;
    }

    // override material paginator page switch
    .mat-mdc-paginator-range-label {
      order: 2;
    }

    .mat-mdc-paginator-navigation-previous {
      order: 1;
    }

    .mat-mdc-paginator-navigation-next {
      order: 3;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I create a solution for how to do it.
I use a `Renderer2` to do the manipulation with `DOM`, and it looks like this:

```
@ViewChild("paginator", {read: ElementRef}) paginator: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this._renderer.insertBefore(
            this.paginator.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-paginator-navigation-next.mat-icon-button').parentNode,
            this.paginator.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-paginator-range-label'),
            this.paginator.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-paginator-navigation-next.mat-icon-button'));
    }
```

In my case `this._renderer` is an instance of `Renderer2`, and also the `HTML` code with `ViewChild` decorator.

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

If someone knows the better solution how to do it, please let me know.
Otherwise, I hope my answer will help you with a similar task.
Thanks