# How to disable ripple effect of Angular Material Pagination button?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, ripple, paginator

I have an Angular Material Paginator which I am currently customizing the css of.

It looks like this:

[image]

I cant record my screen on my device so I will explain.

The two arrow buttons on the right side are Angular Material Icon Buttons.

When I click them, a ripple effect (gray circle) appears. I need to delete that ripple effect.

I couldn't inspect the element where it happens because it only appears on a click.

I checked SO already about this question and the most common answer, to use `[disableRipple]="true"` doesn't work here, since angular paginator does not have this property. I am working in a big project with several developers, so I would not like to touch global scss files.

This is my code btw:

```
<mat-paginator
    #paginator
    (page)="changePage($event)"
    [length]="imagesAndFiles.length"
    [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[4, 8, 16, 24, 32]"
  >
</mat-paginator>
```

How can I remove the ripple effect from the arrow buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to hide the ripple element

- Add a class to the paginator element
- Hide the mat-button-ripple class

```html
<mat-paginator
  class="hide-ripple"
  #paginator
  (page)="changePage($event)"
  [length]="imagesAndFiles.length"
  [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[4, 8, 16, 24, 32]"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

```scss
.hide-ripple {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-button-ripple {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated

Comment: @MoiseScalzo ng-deep is deprecated but is the only way to set global style from inside component. Another option is just writing the css directly in styles.css/scss.

Answer (score 1):

There is a directive called `matRippleDisabled` that can be used in the paginator.

See the [official doc about ripple](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/api#MatRipple)

Comment: Well, this directive could be set to the button, which is abstracted by the `mat-paginator` component. So the question basically narrows down to: How to extract the buttons from `mat-paginator` component in order to set this directive to it?

Comment: You should abstract the logic with a custom paginator, maybe it should help you: [custom paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646259/how-to-customize-mat-paginator-in-angular-material)